# Как пользователю отформатировать фрамент текста в richTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Используется **C#**

**Сценарий.**
Данные из БД попадают в **"dataGridView"**.
Предполагается чтобы при перемещении курсором по записям в **"dataGridView"**,   значение ячейки из строки на которой находится курсор и определённого столбца попадали в **"RichTextBox"**.
Там пользователь при необходимости отформатирует **фрагмент** текста и перейдёт к следующей строке.

При последующих подключениях к БД и попадании курсора на отформатированную ранее запись, ранее изменённый формат снова отображается в **"RichTextBox"**

Пример форматирования на скриншоте.

**Вопрос.**
Как сделать чтобы пользователь мог отформатировать фрагмент текста?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]